# Countif function in Python looping in every cell

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, countif

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beWXG.png)

Hey everyone I am used to work in excel but recently after getting a dataset of about 500k rows that need to be worked in the same worksheet I have huge capacity issues and I was advised to try and transition any function to a python environment. So this excel function `"=IF(COUNTIF($J$2:J3,J3)>1,0,1)"~J` is the column of the Asset ID~ goes to each cell and if it has previous encountered it in the cells above it returns 0 and if it is unique it returns 1.
How that would be possible in a python environment if I load my table as a DataFrame?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas to achieve this very easily:

```
import pandas as pd # import pandas
df = pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx') # use appropriate function according to your file type
df['Unique'] = ~df[Asset_Id].duplicated().astype(int) # places 1 where it is not encountered before, 0 elsewhere
```

Comment: really really thanks might spam the forum until I feel comfortable to regenerate everything through python :)

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it helped! Also look into pandas more thoroughly, its almost everything you're ever gonna need to play with your data.

Comment: It is not working as intended. Summing the column I see that it counts the duplicate values while we would like the first time it encounters a unique ID it would give value 1 and the second time 0 so summing them would give us the number of unique values. The reason i want to run this is that afterwards there are many columns with data and i would be able to count the data by summing only the rows that they have value 1 at our "Unique" column.